# Is it possible to run a docker image directly from ACR

Tags: docker, azure-container-registry

I've created a new simple .Net Core "Hello World" web app.  When I run this locally, it outputs "Hello World" in the browser.  In an effort to familiarise myself with docker and, more specifically, Azure Container Registry, I've created an ACR instance.

According to Azure, this instance has created successfully:

[image: ACR Image]

However, when I try to navigate to the login server address, I get the error "not found" (404) from the browser.

I'm guessing there's something that I need to do before I can navigate to the site.  I've had a look around at various docs and tutorials, but can't see what that might be (incidentally, I'm running this on a Linux container, but building on a Windows system).

Comment: It's difficult to find the error just from your description. Do you mind providing your image? Or the steps you run the image with Docker command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Container Registry is what is says it is, a Contaier Registry. Just like docker hub. This is where you can store your image(s), public or private, it's just someone elses disk.

There is no logic behind that enables you to run the image in ACR and get an externl IP or DNS to navigate to it.

For that, you need to deploy your image to a host, like Kubernetes (container orchestration tool), azure app service or some host.

Compair ACR to let's say Gibhub, it's where you store your source code. Not where it's deployed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/

How to push or pull images:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli